# Change the DateFormat in Bootstrap Datepicker Date Range

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Bootstrap Datepicker Date Range. Now I am getting DateFormat as mm/dd/yyyy. but I need to change this to dd/mm/yyyy. Can anyone please help me on this.?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var nowTemp = new Date();
                var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

                var checkin = $('#AvailableFrom').datepicker({
                    onRender: function (date) {
                        date = new Date();
                        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';

                    }
                }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                    if (ev.date.valueOf() > checkout.date.valueOf()) {
                        var newDate = new Date(ev.date);
                        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                        checkout.setValue(newDate);
                    }
                    checkin.hide();
                    $('#AvailableTo')[0].focus();
                }).data('datepicker');
                var checkout = $('#AvailableTo').datepicker({
                    onRender: function (date) {
                        return date.valueOf() <= checkin.date.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                    }
                }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                    checkout.hide();
                }).data('datepicker');
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`format` option](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#format) of bootstrap datepicker.

```
var checkin = $('#AvailableFrom').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",  // here you can update the date format
    onRender: function (date) {
        date = new Date();
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L00jmq1k/1/) with a simple example